# Check if user has CREATE DATABASE permissions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to check if the currently logged in user to my SQL server has permissions to create databases.

I've tried the following statements:

`SELECT HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME(db_name(), 'DATABASE', 'CREATE')`

`SELECT HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME(null, 'DATABASE', 'CREATE')`

`SELECT HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME(null, null, 'CREATE DATABASE')`

But every single one of them returns `NULL` instead of `1`, although I indeed have permissions to create new databases.

I assume it should return `1` by running `SELECT HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME(null, null, 'VIEW SERVER STATE');`, which returns `1` :)

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

On my test system, I'm able to run this successfully:

```
SELECT has_perms_by_name(null, null, 'CREATE ANY DATABASE');
```

That permission is slightly different than `CREATE DATABASE`, but might work for you.

Answer (score 1):

I might have just [found it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176015.aspx).

`SELECT IS_SRVROLEMEMBER ( 'dbcreator' )`

Comment: I don't think that will work. Specifically, that checks only that method of granting the permission to create databases.

Comment: @BenThul Are you sure about that? Because the documentation specifically states `Indicates whether a SQL Server login is a member of the specified server role.`. And that's the role that has CREATE DATABASE permissions.

Comment: Right. But what if I do `grant create database to someLogin`?

Comment: @BenThul Now I understand what you mean. I am aware that there are multiple ways to grant `CREATE DATABASE` permissions, the `dbcreator` role being one of them. And my code only covers one of the many possibilities. Alright, got it. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME(NULL, 'DATABASE', 'CREATE DATABASE')
```